# Taking the derivative of $\epsilon \cdot(\ln X + \ln \beta) - \ln(1 + X^{\frac{\alpha}{\alpha - 1}})$ with respect to $\ln X$

Tags: calculus, derivatives, partial-derivative

So I am taking the derivative of 
$$\epsilon \cdot(\ln X + \ln \beta) - \ln(1 + X^{\frac{\alpha}{\alpha - 1}})$$ with respect to $\ln X$, where $X$ is a variable, $\epsilon, \beta, \alpha$ are constants.

I come up with 
$$ \epsilon + \frac{\alpha}{1-\alpha} \frac{X^{\frac{\alpha}{\alpha-1}}}{1+X^{\frac{\alpha}{\alpha-1}}}$$
using the fact that $$\frac{\partial f(X)}{\partial \ln X} = \frac{\partial f(X)}{\partial X}\cdot \bigg (\frac{\partial \ln X}{\partial X}\bigg )^{-1}$$

If possible, could someone check my work? Or, more specifically, I am curious about whether the $X^{\frac{\alpha}{\alpha-1}}$ numerator, which comes from $X^{\frac{\alpha}{\alpha-1} - 1} X$, is correct. The $-1$ exponent from taking a derivative cancels out with the $\bigg (\frac{\partial \ln X}{\partial X}\bigg )^{-1}$, and I'm unsure if I'm correct on that.

Even if the example was more complicated, like
$$
\frac{\partial ln(1 + X^2 + X^{15} + X^{-20})}{\partial \ln X}
$$
the subtracting $1$ from each power in the numerator of the result would be undone by multipying by $X$. I'm not sure I'm correct on this, though.

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest thing to do is just define $Y = \log X$, hence $X = e^Y$, and express the given function in terms of $Y$: $$f(Y) = \epsilon (Y + \log \beta) - \log \left( 1 + \exp\left(\frac{\alpha}{\alpha-1} Y \right) \right).$$  Then $$\frac{\partial f}{\partial Y} = \epsilon - \left(1 + \exp\left(\frac{\alpha}{\alpha-1} Y \right) \right)^{-1} \frac{\alpha}{\alpha-1} \exp \left(\frac{\alpha}{\alpha-1} Y\right),$$ and re-expressing this in terms of $X$ gives $$\frac{\partial f}{\partial \log X} = \epsilon - \left(1 + X^{\alpha/(\alpha-1)}\right)^{-1} \frac{\alpha}{\alpha-1} X^{\alpha/(\alpha-1)}.$$